# How do I read all the files in a folder after storing them inside a directory so that I can perform some action on them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, valueerror

I am able to open all the files in a folder using `os.listdir`, but after that how do I read every file and then execute some code on them?

```py
encode  = 'ANSI'
file_paths = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\TMPFQB\\Documents\\MY PROJECTS\\Jan 2024')
for file_path in range(len(file_paths)):
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding = encode) as f:
        Jan_txt = f.readlines()[4:]
```

With this code, I get the following error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 6
      4 file_paths = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\TMPFQB\\Documents\\MY PROJECTS\\Jan 2024')
      5 for file_path in range(len(file_paths)):
----> 6     with open(file_path, 'r', encoding = encode) as f:
      7         Jan_txt = f.readlines()[4:]

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:280, in _modified_open(file, *args, **kwargs)
    277 @functools.wraps(io_open)
    278 def _modified_open(file, *args, **kwargs):
    279     if file in {0, 1, 2}:
--> 280         raise ValueError(
    281             f"IPython won't let you open fd={file} by default "
    282             "as it is likely to crash IPython. If you know what you are doing, "
    283             "you can use builtins' open."
    284         )
    286     return io_open(file, *args, **kwargs)

ValueError: IPython won't let you open fd=0 by default as it is likely to crash IPython. If you know what you are doing, you can use builtins' open.
```

Below shows how I intend to combine the whole text into one string, then use reGex to pull out what I need:
(but I am stuck on trying to be able to execute this on every file in the folder)

```py
whole_txt = "".join(Jan_16_txt)
matches = re.findall(pattern, whole_txt, flags = re.MULTILINE)
Jan_16 = [[m[8], m[12], m[27], m[29]] for m in matches]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = Jan_16)
```

Comment: please try to iterate over `file_paths` directly without `len`and `range` - at the moment you have only an integer (0) stored in file_path in your loop. `for file_path in file_paths` would be more adequate. Then you have the filenames stored in the variable `file_path` and with `os.path.join(root, file_path)` you can join the strings to one valid filepath and read it.

Comment: Have you tried running your script outside of the notebook?

Comment: @JKupzig removing `len` & `range` resolved that error, thanks. I am pretty new to python, may I know where to place `os.path.join(root, file_path)` , and which variable do I assign it to?

Comment: @CtrlZ I am not sure where else to run it other than jupyter notebook... please advise.

Comment: The answer from xArbisRox is one possible solution where to put or how to implement the `os.path.join` - another would be, to define it just below the for-statement, e.g. `for (file_name in file_paths):; file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name); with open(file_path, 'r', encoding = encode) as file: ...`
Where `root`is 'C:\\Users\\TMPFQB\\Documents\\MY PROJECTS\\Jan 2024'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested and explained by @JKupzig in the comment, the issue is with your iteration, not referencing the path of the according files to open.

```
base_path = r'C:\Users\TMPFQB\Documents\MY PROJECTS\Jan 2024'

# List of files in above directory, making sure no directories are included
file_names = [file_name for file_name in os.listdir(base_path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(base_path, file_name))]

# You can also do this in above list comprehension directly, but to make it easier to understand...
# Create absolute paths to these files
file_paths = [os.path.join(base_path, file_name) for file_name in file_names]

for file_path in file_paths:
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding = encode) as f:
        .... # your logic
```